# Правильное склонение слова "х*й"

Tags: склонение, обсценная-лексика

Если я хочу сказать кому-то, что я вращал его на своём детородном органе, будет ли это звучать как "Да я тебя на хуе вертел" или "Да я тебя на хую вертел"? Очень интересно, ведь по логике правил должно быть "на хуе", но слышал я почему-то только второй вариант.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110657/discussion-on-question-by-rainbowcat13----).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Предположу, что это тот редкий случай, когда мы можем говорить о местном падеже, так называемом "втором предложном". Пример со словом край: "в крае" (пр. п.), "в краю" (местный п.).

Аналогичным образом происходит и со словом "хуй". А на вопрос "почему" вряд ли можно ответить что-то, кроме "потому". Так сложилось, и всё. Думаю, ритм у фразы просто более благозвучный. Нет паузы.

Comment: Аналогично: Она лежала на шкафу. Я её на шкафу вертел.

Comment: Главное, чтобы ритм был благозвучный у фразы.

Answer (score 3):

Строго говоря, к обсценной лексике вопрос относится весьма косвенно, вопрос-то, если разобраться, о местной форме предложного падежа.

По сути - ответ дан, это ***местная форма предложного падежа***.

Мне хочется добавить (для @Третийглаз прежде всего) несколько фраз, в комментарии явно не влезают.

Вы всё правильно пишете по сути вопроса, но, боюсь, сильно запутались в понятии местного падежа (и предложного соответственно). У слова "край" допустимы две формы местного - собственно местная (на краю) и обычная предложная (на крае). Не надо их противопоставлять. Противопоставление, строго говоря, идет именно по предлогам: если предлог В или НА, то это местный падеж (кроме случаев, когда у сочетания нет значения места и времени - "ориентироваться в лесу" - умение определять направления, "ориентироваться в лесе" - разбираться в ценах на лес как материал), если же предлог О, ОБО, ПРИ и в ПО (последнее - при местоимениях, а при существительных - либо в значении "после", либо в архаичных конструкциях типа "по ком звонит колокол" и в просторечиях), то падеж имеет семантику обычного предлдожного.

В этом смысле наш король русского мата относится к небольшой группе слов, где правила эти соблюдаются нестрого. При предлоге НА он требует формы локатива, а с предлогом В - обычного предложного. Таких слов (вроде бы) больше нет, но есть масса других интересных исключений.

Среди таких исключений помимо упоминавшегося слова "край" (которое наряду с "дуб","ряд" и некоторыми другими допускает обе формы для семантики местного падежа) есть еще слово "полк" (которое вопреки утверждениям многих лингвистов вообще не имеет употребительной формы неместного предложного - при полку, о полку и т. д.) и еще некоторые особые слова.

Подробности про предложный падеж см. тут
http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6

А для особо интересующихся рекомендую лекцию Ильи Иткина
https://m.polit.ru/article/2016/08/20/itkin_lecture/

Comment: Вы, конечно, правы насчёт отношения вопроса к обсценной лексике, но просто именно о склонении этого слова я задумался сначала (что, конечно, не характеризует меня как высококультурного человека), и потому решил спросить именно про него, а не про другое.

Comment: @Rainbowcat13 я не имел в виду делать вам какие-то замечания.